# What differences could happen if a project is just built with OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

I am working in c++ using Visual Studio 2012. I would like to know the difference between these below case,

1. I have built my application by enabling the openmp but I did not do parallel programming. I mean I did not use the #pragma etc in any of my code.
2. I have built my application by disabling the openmp and I did not do any parallel programming.

In such case, what kind of changes or issues possible, for example applicaion size etc.

Comment: Did you try it? Did you see any differences?

Comment: I have tried with a sample project. I could not catch anything. As visual studio has given it as an option, I would like to know the reason behind it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling with OpenMP activated might have some effect, even if no OpenMP directives are enabled. However, from a code's result standpoint, it shouldn't make any difference. Only can it make a difference in term of performance, due to the compiler selecting a different set of heuristics to optimise the code. For example, aggressive optimisations consuming a large amount of memory bandwidth can be disabled while compiling for OpenMP (even if no OpenMP directives are included in the code), while these optimisations are enabled for non-parallel code. Likewise, compiling for OpenMP usually imply linking with thread-safe versions of libraries (if applicable), which might be a bit less optimised than the non-thread-safe ones. But altogether, I doubt you will see any difference at all, unless you fall into a very corner case.

Just as an example, here is a excerpt from the man page of an (old) version of the Intel C compiler:

```
    -opt-mem-bandwidth<n> (i64, L*X only)
          Enables  or  disables  performance  tuning and heuristics
          that control memory bandwidth use among  processors.   It
          allows  the compiler to be less aggressive with optimiza-
          tions that might consume  more  bandwidth,  so  that  the
          bandwidth  can  be  well-shared among multiple processors
          for a parallel program.  For values of <n>  greater  than
          0,  the option tells the compiler to enable a set of per-
          formance tuning and heuristics in compiler  optimizations
          such   as  prefetching,  privatization,  aggressive  code
          motion, and so forth, for reducing memory bandwidth pres-
          sure   and   balancing  memory  bandwidth  traffic  among
          threads.  The <n> value is the level  of  optimizing  for
          memory  bandwidth  usage. You can specify one of the fol-
          lowing values for <n>:

          0 -- Disables a set of performance tuning and  heuristics
          in compiler optimizations for parallel code.  This is the
          default for serial code.

          1 -- Enables a set of performance tuning  and  heuristics
          in  compiler  optimizations for multithreaded code gener-
          ated by the compiler.  This is the  default  if  compiler
          option  -parallel  or  -openmp  is  specified, or Cluster
          OpenMP option -cluster-openmp is specified (see the Clus-
          ter OpenMP documentation).

          2  --  Enables a set of performance tuning and heuristics
          in compiler optimizations for parallel code such as  Win-
          dows  Threads,  pthreads,  and  MPI  code, besides multi-
          threaded code generated by the compiler.
```

So as you can see, enabling or not OpenMP had some possible performance side effects since default was normally `-opt-mem-bandwidth0` but became `-opt-mem-bandwidth1` if OpenMP support was turned on.
Likewise, I remember the IBM compiler had somewhat similar changes in performance heuristics for multi-threaded codes. I' wouldn't be surprised this sort of selective behaviour is still applied internally, and even for the Microsoft compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely nothing. Take the simple example of

```
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output assembler is *exactly* the same with and without the /openmp flag (with /O2, but similar results with no optimizations)

```
; Listing generated by Microsoft (R) Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.61030.0 

    TITLE
    .686P
    .XMM
    include listing.inc
    .model  flat

INCLUDELIB OLDNAMES

PUBLIC  ??_C@_0N@NLPDAPMJ@Hello?5world?6?$AA@       ; `string'
EXTRN   __imp__printf:PROC
EXTRN   @__security_check_cookie@4:PROC
;   COMDAT ??_C@_0N@NLPDAPMJ@Hello?5world?6?$AA@
CONST   SEGMENT
??_C@_0N@NLPDAPMJ@Hello?5world?6?$AA@ DB 'Hello world', 0aH, 00H ; `string'
CONST   ENDS
PUBLIC  _main
; Function compile flags: /Ogtp
;   COMDAT _main
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 5    :    printf("Hello world\n");

    push    OFFSET ??_C@_0N@NLPDAPMJ@Hello?5world?6?$AA@
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__printf
    add esp, 4

; 6    :    return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 7    : }

    ret 0
_main   ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

OpenMP is a set of compiler directive (which I didn't use), library routines (which I didn't link to), and some environment variables (again, not used). There is therefore no reason that the output program will be any different. Even including `omp.h` doesn't change anything (except in the comment lines).